# Elasticsearch: How to use two different multiple matching fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do something much like the ['and' filter example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/) except with terms with a 'should' in each one, instead of the field types in the example. I came up with the following:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "foo",
            "values": [
              "fff",
              "bar",
              "baz",
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "term": {
                "fruit": [
                  "orange",
                  "apple",
                  "pear",
                ]
              }
            },
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "term": {
                "color": [
                  "red",
                  "yellow",
                  "green"
                ]
              }
            },
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
[bool] filter does not support [minimum_should_match];
```

Is there another way to go about what I'm attempting to do, or am I on the right track? Or is this just not possible in elasticsearch?

Comment: As the error message says, bool filters don't support minimum_should_match; bool queries do.  Can you explain what you're trying to do in English?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each bool query clause can contain multiple clauses.  A terms query (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query/) is an easy way to specify that the query should match any of a list of terms.  Here's that uses terms queries to say fruit must be one of orange, apple, pear and color must be one of red, yellow, green, in addition to the ids query you had before:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "foo",
            "values": [
              "fff",
              "bar",
              "baz"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "fruit": [ "orange", "apple","pear" ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [ "red", "yellow", "green" ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you really use `minimum_should_match` like that without a `should` filter? I assumed you couldn't.

Comment: OMG this works. This query is the most beautiful thing I've seen in weeks. I'm going to name my firstborn "stackoverflow".

Comment: what about phrases, can i do something similar? if i want to do a query where all i want is to see which docs match at least one of the phrases i provide

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/). If I understand right what you are trying to accomplish, [terms filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-filter/) with [and filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/) should be enough. So something like this:

```
# Delete index
#
curl -s -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test' ; echo

# Create index
#
curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "color": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "fruit": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' ; echo

# Index some documents
#
curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/1?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "apple",
  "color" : "red"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/2?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "apple",
  "color" : "yellow"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/3?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "apple",
  "color" : "green"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/4?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "banana",
  "color" : "green"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/5?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "banana",
  "color" : "yellow"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/6?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "pear",
  "color" : "green"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/7?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "pear",
  "color" : "yellow"
}' ; echo

curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/document/7?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fruit" : "pear",
  "color" : "red"
}' ; echo


# Refresh index
#
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/_refresh'; echo


# This query should return only red apples and pears
#
curl -s -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/bool-filter-test/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "filter" : {
    "and" : [
      {
        "terms" : { "fruit" : ["apple", "pear"] }
      },
      {
        "terms" : { "color" : ["red"] }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

You can even specify `execution` to `bool` (which according to documentation) `Generates a term filter (which is cached) for each term, and wraps those in a bool filter. The bool filter itself is not cached as it can operate very quickly on the cached term filters.`