# Elasticsearch Array (Label/Tag Querying

Tags: elasticsearch

I really think that I'm trying to do is fairly simple. I'm simply trying to query for N tags. A clear example of this was asked and answered over at "[Elasticsearch: How to use two different multiple matching fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990496/elasticsearch-how-to-use-two-different-multiple-matching-fields)". Yet, that solution doesn't seem to work for the latest version of ES (more likely, I'm simply doing it wrong).

To show the current data and to demonstrate a working query, see below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
             "filter": { 
                 "terms": { 
                    "Price": [10,5]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results for this. As you can see, 5 and 10 are showing up (this demonstrates that basic queries do work):

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "labelsample",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "AVLGnGMYXB5vRcKBZaDw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "Category" : [ "Medium Signs" ],
        "Code" : "a",
        "Name" : "Sample 1",
        "Timestamp" : 1.455031083799152E9,
        "Price" : "10",
        "IsEnabled" : true
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "labelsample",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "AVLGnGHHXB5vRcKBZaDF",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "Category" : [ "Small Signs" ],
        "Code" : "b",
        "Name" : "Sample 2",
        "Timestamp" : 1.45503108346191E9,
        "Price" : "5",
        "IsEnabled" : true
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "labelsample",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "AVLGnGILXB5vRcKBZaDO",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "Category" : [ "Medium Signs" ],
        "Code" : "c",
        "Name" : "Sample 3",
        "Timestamp" : 1.455031083530215E9,
        "Price" : "10",
        "IsEnabled" : true
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "labelsample",
      "_type" : "entry",
      "_id" : "AVLGnGGgXB5vRcKBZaDA",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "Category" : [ "Medium Signs" ],
        "Code" : "d",
        "Name" : "Sample 4",
        "Timestamp" : 1.4550310834233E9,
        "Price" : "10",
        "IsEnabled" : true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

As a side note: the following bool query gives the exact same results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "Price": [10,5]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice `Category`...

Let's simply copy/paste Category into a query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
             "filter": { 
                 "terms": { 
                    "Category" : [ "Medium Signs" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following gem:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Again, here's the bool query version that gives the same 0-hit result:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "Category" : [ "Medium Signs" ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, I definitely need something similar to `"Category" : [ "Medium Signs", "Small Signs" ]` working (in concert with other label queries and `minimum_should_match` as well-- but **I can't even get this bare-bones query to work**).

I have zero clue why this is. I poured over the docs for houring, trying everything I can see. Do I need to look into debugging various encodings? Is my syntax archaic?

Comment: Isn't because your `Category` field already is an array?

Comment: can you please update the question with mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that ElasticSearch is analyzing and betokening the Category field, and the terms filter expects an exact match.  One solution here is to add a raw field to Category inside your entry mapping:

```
PUT labelsample
{
  "mappings": {
    "entry": {
      "properties": {
        "Category": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "Code": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "Price": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IsEnabled": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...and filter on the raw field:

```
GET labelsample/entry/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
             "filter": { 
                 "terms": { 
                    "Category.raw" : [ "Medium Signs" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help.